# Swift Protocol Implements Equatable

Tags: swift, swift2, protocols, equatable

I have the the below `Protocol`:

```
protocol Cacheable {
    //....//
    func identifier() -> String
}
```

Can I make `Cacheable` implements Equatable ?

when I do the following:

```
extension Cacheable: Equatable {}

func ==(lhs:Cacheable,rhs:Cacheable) -> Bool {

     return lhs.identifier() == rhs.identifier()
}
```

I got this error message : **Extension of protocol `Cacheable` cannot have an inheritance clause**

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## 1) Allow two `Cacheable`s of the same type to be compare

```
protocol Cacheable: Equatable {
    //....//
    func identifier() -> String
}

func ==<T : Cacheable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs.identifier() == rhs.identifier()
}
```

### Pros

This is the simplest solution.

### Cons

You can only compare two `Cacheable` objects of the same type. This means that code below will fail and in order to fix it you need to make `Animal` conform to `Cacheable`:

```
class Animal {

}

class Dog: Animal,Cacheable {
    func identifier() -> String {
        return "object"
    }
}

class Cat: Animal,Cacheable {
    func identifier() -> String {
        return "object"
    }
}

let a = Dog()

let b = Cat()

a == b //such comparison is not allowed
```

## 2) Allow `Cacheable`s of any type to be compared

```
protocol Cacheable:Equatable {
    //....//
    func identifier() -> String
}

func ==<T:Cacheable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs.identifier() == rhs.identifier()
}

func !=<T:Cacheable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs.identifier() != rhs.identifier()
}

func ==<T:Cacheable, U:Cacheable>(lhs: T, rhs: U) -> Bool {
    return lhs.identifier() == rhs.identifier()
}

func !=<T:Cacheable, U:Cacheable>(lhs: T, rhs: U) -> Bool {
    return lhs.identifier() != rhs.identifier()
}
```

### Pros

Removes limitations described above for solution 1. Now you can easily compare `Dog` and `Cat`.

### Cons

- Implementation is longer. Actually I am not sure why specifying only `==` functions is not sufficient - this might be a bug with a compiler. Anyway, you have to provide the implementation for both `==` and `!=`.
- In some cases the benefit of this implementation may also pose a problem as you are allowing the comparison between absolutely different objects and compiler is totally OK with it.

## 3) Without conforming to `Equatable`

```
protocol Cacheable {
    //....//
    func identifier() -> String
}

func ==(lhs: Cacheable, rhs: Cacheable) -> Bool {
    return lhs.identifier() == rhs.identifier()
}

func !=(lhs: Cacheable, rhs: Cacheable) -> Bool {
    return lhs.identifier() != rhs.identifier()
}
```

### Pros

You can use `Cacheable` as type without needing any generics. This introduces a whole new range of possibilities. For example:

```
let c:[Cacheable] = [Dog(),RaceCar()]

c[0] == c[1]
c[0] != c[1]
```

With solutions 1 and 2 such code would fail and you would have to use generics in your classes. However, with the latest implementation `Cacheable` is treated as a type, so you are allowed to declare an array of type `[Cacheable]`.

### Cons

You no longer declare conformance to `Equatable` so any functions which accept `Equatable` parameters will not accept `Cacheable`. Obviously, apart from `==` and `!=` as we declared them for `Cacheable`s.

If this is not a problem in your code I would actually prefer this solution. Being able to treat protocol as a type is super useful in many cases.

Comment: I did before and I got : `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two Cacheable operands` when trying to compare two object implements `Cacheable`

Comment: That's why I used generics ;) This code works. I have tested it right now with Xcode 7 beta 5

Comment: Don't use playground. Try putting it in code. Drop it in AppDelegate of one of your apps and check it in the willFinishLaunching function

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Works perfectly in swift 2.1

Comment: Doesn't work. I think that's because both lhs and rhs might be of different types and swift doesn't have a way of telling whether or not you are checking different types. Example: Type1() and Type2 both conform to Cacheable. Now trying Type1() as Cacheable == Type2() as Cacheable -> Error. Cannot be applied to two operands of type Cacheable.

Comment: yep. That's what I was saying. They have to be of the same type for it to work. I wanted to make the == on the protocol type. I didn't care if they were different objects as long as they had the same properties I wanted to consider them the same.

Comment: I ended up creating a "isEqualTo(protocol)" to have this behaviour. Not perfect but I prefer that than adding a class in the middle to haven them both be of the same common type.

Comment: @NunoGonçalves can you check my updated answer to see if any of the alternative solutions fits your needs?

Comment: That's it! Changing the "==" implementation to have two types works. :) Of course... Thanks!

Comment: @NunoGonçalves have you checked the 3rd solution? In my view it is by far the simplest one, although I might be missing some use case when conformance to Equatable is extremely necessary :)

Comment: Note that with #2, once Cachable extends Equatable, it inherits a Self reference which means it can no longer be used as a type. ie. `let x:Cachable = ...` becomes invalid. This is a huge issue with Swift's protocols and can be difficult, if not impossible to hack around depending on what you are doing.

Comment: You're right. I'm mistaken. I don't know what I did. Sorry.

Answer (score 11):

Try.

```
extension Equatable where Self : Cacheable {
}
```

Comment: This seems not to work:  I defined a class `class MyClass : Cacheable { ... }` and tried to pass an instance of that class to a function `func foo<T : Equatable>(obj : T)` and that did not compile. (Btw.: An identical solution was posted and deleted later because it does not work.)

Comment: same, getting Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'SubtitleTrack' operands, where SubtitleTrack is a protocol using this extension :(