# I don`t know why error happen

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make that Post protocol inheritance Equatable protocol and Post protocol implements method in Equatable protocol.

I don`t know why error happen....

please help me... I want to know why error happen..

(== method of Equatable protocol in swift 3.0 is static method. therefore, I use static method.)

```
protocol Post: Equatable {
    var referenceIndex: Int { get set}
    var likeCount: Int { get set}
    var likeStatus: Bool { get set}
    var commentCount: Int { get set}
    var commentStatus: Bool { get set}
}

// here. error happen...
extension Post {
    public static func ==(lhs: Post, rhs: Post) -> Bool {
        return lhs.referenceIndex == rhs.referenceIndex
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468051/4063602)

Your `==` method should not be added in an `extension`, it should be added globally. Even though it might seem to be a `static` method, it should still be declared as a global function. You can find a discussion about the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246003/why-must-a-protocol-operator-be-implemented-as-a-global-function).

Now...if you had declared your `Post` as a `struct` or a `class` then yes, you could have added a `static ==` method inside your `struct/class`. However, you have declared a `protocol` and a `protocol` can not have any methods.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921972/swift-protocol-implements-equatable) shows you how to have a `protocol` implement `Equatable`.

Armed with all that we can implement your `Post protocol` and have it implement `Equatable` like so:

```
protocol Post: Equatable {
    var referenceIndex: Int { get set}
    var likeCount: Int { get set}
    var likeStatus: Bool { get set}
    var commentCount: Int { get set}
    var commentStatus: Bool { get set}
}

func ==<T : Post>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs.referenceIndex == rhs.referenceIndex
}
```

And then, to prove that things are working:

```
struct SomePost: Post {
    var referenceIndex: Int
    var likeCount: Int
    var likeStatus: Bool
    var commentCount: Int
    var commentStatus: Bool
}

let somePost1 = SomePost(referenceIndex: 1, likeCount: 1, likeStatus: true, commentCount: 1, commentStatus: true)
let somePost2 = SomePost(referenceIndex: 2, likeCount: 1, likeStatus: true, commentCount: 1, commentStatus: true)
let somePost3 = SomePost(referenceIndex: 1, likeCount: 1, likeStatus: true, commentCount: 1, commentStatus: true)

somePost1 == somePost2 //false
somePost1 == somePost3 //true
```

Hope that helps you

Comment: == method of Equatable protocol in swift 3.0 is static method.
therefore, I use static method.

Comment: @user3427989 I've updated my question to make it work with protocols and tried to explain why it shouldn't be a static method (hope I succeeded :))

Comment: you're welcome, good luck :)